# how to add new columns after calculations

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame:

```
               Open     High      Low    Close AdjClose    Volume
datetime                                                         
2018-07-27  28.8200  29.3350  27.7050  28.1300  28.1300   8101362
2018-07-26  28.4800  29.1200  27.5500  28.9800  28.9800  10582061
2018-07-25  30.0900  30.0900  28.4800  28.9800  28.9800   9801897
2018-07-24  30.4500  30.9400  29.9650  30.1400  30.1400   5706941
2018-07-23  31.1100  31.3500  30.6000  30.8200  30.8200   6023310
```

I want to calculate two new columns in the following for loop (i am using python 2.7.15 and also, i am not a programmer).
this is my loop:

```
A=pd.DataFrame(df)
print (A.head(5))
Len=len(A)
print (Len)
for Rw in range(Len-1):
    def adj(A):
        BB=float(A.iloc[Rw,4])
        CC=float(A.iloc[Rw+1,4])
        #print (BB,CC)

        if BB>CC:
            x1=BB-CC
            x2=0   
            print(x1,x2)
        else:
            x1=0
            x2=CC-BB
            print(x1,x2)

        A.at[Rw+1,'Up']=x1   #Store calculation results in Up column
        A.at[Rw+1,'Down']=x2 #Store calculation results in Down column  

    adj(A)

print(A.head(5))
```

when i enable ==> A.at[Rw+1, 'up']=x1 , i got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Yossi\eclipse-workspace_yossi\Tests\to_forum___003.py", line 85, in <module>
    adj(A)
  File "D:\Yossi\eclipse-workspace_yossi\Tests\to_forum___003.py", line 82, in adj
    A.at[Rw+1,'Up']=x1      #Store calculation results in UpMv columns
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2159, in __setitem__
    self.obj._set_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2587, in _set_value
    self.loc[index, col] = value
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 189, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 375, in _setitem_with_indexer
    labels = index.insert(len(index), key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 2194, in insert
    "cannot insert DatetimeIndex with incompatible label")
TypeError: cannot insert DatetimeIndex with incompatible label
```

How can i see the calculation results of x1 in column 'Up' and results of x2 in column 'Down' with the DataFrame, like the following picture?

[image]

Thank you all.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use a loop for this. I suggest you look up `pd.Series.shift`.

Comment: Why not? at column 'Adj Close', i calculate row 1 with row 2, and i need to store the calculation result in column Up or Down. then i jump to calculate row 2 with row 3, and store this result in column Up or down, below the previous results, and so on, until the last row.

Comment: See [@DYZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51584791/9209546).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a LOT of things that are wrong with the original code, starting with defining a function in a loop. Here's a compact, efficient, pandas/numpy-based solution:

```
import numpy as np
difference = df['Close'] - df['Close'].shift()
df['Up'] = -np.minimum(difference, 0)
df['Down'] = np.maximum(difference, 0)
```

Comment: I tried to use this code as you wrote, but still i got same error. i know that my loop code is too complicated and not efficient, but i want to use my code anyway (more easy for me to understand....as i mentioned, i am not a programmer, and  i don't think my loop code is incorrect). If i disable adj(A) in the end of the loop code, i see DataFrame without the columns that i want to add (i.e Up and Down) and it seemed logical. But, if i enable this adj(A), i got error: TypeError: cannot insert DatetimeIndex with incompatible label.

Comment: few month ago, this code works well (i used python 2.7.9 i think....and i download data from yahoo, until the API blocked. now, i am using python 2.7.15, with alphavantage API). i think something wrong with adj(A) and i don't understand where, i tried to change locations...nothing.